# Student t-distribution different values

Tags: java, r, apache-commons-math

When I run student t-distribution in `R`, I get following:

```
> pt(1.849, 2, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.1028493
```

When I run same with `Apache Commons Math` library, I get following:

```
  TDistribution td = new TDistribution(2);
  System.out.println(td.density(1.849));
  O/P: 0.07927663297535456
```

Values are completely different. Is this expected behavior (or) Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**
When I used `cumulativeProbability` I got following output, which is also far different from R value.

```
0.8954597327733625
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from Apache Common Math seems to be the value of the density function.

```
> dt(1.849, 2)
[1] 0.07927663
```

Comment: Make sense, then what method in TDistribution should I use to get pt?

Comment: I never used this library but a quick look at the apache doc suggest that you should use the method cumulativeProbability http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/TDistribution.html

Comment: I did try cumulative probability, but values are no where near.

Comment: @Nambari Well you're specifiying lower.tail=FALSE in R but not specifying that same condition in java.  To get the upper tail in Java you could manually just subtract the value you get from 1.

Comment: @Dason: Thanks for the suggestion! you are correct, 1-value solved the problem. I looked at isLowerBoundSupportincl....() which returned false and thought lower.tail condition satisfied, my mistake. Please change your comment as answer, I will accept it.